# Linear Transformations given vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm having trouble understanding how to solve linear transformations given a vector transforming into another vector. Any suggestions for the example below? This is not merely someone trying to get a homework answer, but rather a *simple* explanation to someone taking Linear Algebra for the first time.

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a linear transformation that sends the vector $u=(5,2)$ into $(2,1)$ and maps $v =(1,3)$ into $(−1,3)$. Calculate $T(-3u), T(7v),$ and $T(-3u+7v)$.

Comment: Hint: a linear mapping $T$ on $V$ satisfies $T(x + y) = T(x) + T(y)$ and $T(kx) = kT(x)$.

Comment: Regarding the downvotes, you should know that if something looks like a homework problem many moderators will expect some effort from you like showing what you have tried to solve the problem and where you get stuck or we would easily be flooded in lots of homework questions on this site.

Comment: @mathreader: thanks for the suggestion, but it's actually not a homework question. During my previous lecture my professor taught this and I didn't understand it at all. So, I went to my textbook and this was a sample problem. I'm not trying to cheat the system--I simply want to learn how to do this so I can succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $T(5,2)=(2,1)$ and $T(1,3)=(-1,3)$. So $T(-3(5,2))=-3T(5,2)=-3(2,1)=(-6,-3)$. $T(7(1,3))=7(-1,3)=(-7,21)$. Now do the third one. The definition of Linear Transformation is mentioned by @SeanRoberson in the comment. Apply that.

Comment: Thank you! You offered perhaps the most clear and concise answer I was looking for--thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: @Joanne: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: Ok good to know! Thanks @MårtenW

Answer (score 1):

Think of the definition of a linear transformation. Suppose $T$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $T$ satisfies the followings:

(1) For all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $T(x+y) = T(x)+T(y)$ (Addition)

(2) For all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $T(\lambda x) = \lambda T(x)$ (Scalar multiplication)

These are things that we need for solving the problem. In other words, there is no need for calculating the exact value of the matrix representation of $T$. In the problem, we have
$$ T(u) = \begin{pmatrix}2\\ 1\end{pmatrix}, \quad T(v) = \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$$
for $u^T = (5,2)$ and $v^T = (1,3)$. And the calculation for $T(-3u),T(7v),$ and $T(-3u+7v)$ can be derived from the definition above.
$$\begin{align}T(-3u) &= -3T(u) \quad (\text{by the definition (2)})\\
&= -3\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ -3\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$
Likewise, $T(7v)$ becomes $\begin{pmatrix}-7\\ 21\end{pmatrix}$. By using the definition (1), the calculation of $T(-3u + 7v)$ becomes $T(-3u) + T(7v)$ and we can easily get the result by simply adding up the previous calculations.

Answer (score -3):

You can pose this as a linear least squares problem if you first remake your matrix into a vector with a process called *vectorization*, then we can write multiplication with another matrix or a vector as a matrix multiplication with a vectorized matrix. You can find a quite good description how to do this on [This wikipedia site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) under "Matrix equations".

You will get a matrix equation system of the type $\bf Mx =b$ which you can solve for example with linear least squares.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I feel the level of the answer is not well adapted to the questioner, and I can understand that it attracts negative reactions. Someone struggling to learn the basics of linear transformations is not likely to be fluent in linear least-squares.

Comment: @Mårten : You are right, it is not intended to be too detailed or easy. Sometimes if we feed the answers too easily people will stop trying to find them for themselves and it will reinforce a bird-bread begging behaviour which really does not motivate anyone to become good at learning mathematics.

Comment: @mathreader: My point is that leading the questioner to undertake an unnecessarily complicated approach is uncalled for.

Comment: It would be good for them. Even if they don't understand it now. What do you know about unnecessary? Maybe it will prove extremely useful for them in 10-15 years time.

Comment: @mathreader: I'm not advising against teaching least-squares, but I _am_ advising against using heavy least-squares machinery for learning (or rather avoiding to learn) the basic concepts of linear transformations. (Especially if doing the least-squares in terms of matrices - that would be a foul application of circular reasoning.)

Comment: It would not be circular reasoning in any sense. That matrix multiplication behaves that way related to Kronecker products is an extremely important property. Also if it is the case that the asker of the question is taking a first linear algebra course at college or university, then it is even more important to stress the fact that they need to **work** on the problems and not expect answers on a silver platter. Otherwise they won't learn how to learn, and that would be even worse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66292/discussion-between-marten-w-and-mathreadler).